# CMake error: 'target is not built by this project'

Tags: c++, opencv, cmake, clion

My `CMakeLists.txt` file is:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.7)
project(OpenCV_Basics)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)

set(SOURCE_FILES main.cpp)

find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED)
include_directories(${OpenCV_INCLUDE_LIBS})
target_link_libraries(OpenCV_Basics )

add_executable(OpenCV_Basics ${SOURCE_FILES})
```

When I tried to compile the main.cpp, I got stucked.

```
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:10 (target_link_libraries):
  Cannot specify link libraries for target "OpenCV_Basics" which is not 
built
  by this project.
```

What's wrong?

I am working in Clion on Mac.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

add_executable defines a target, but on your code you define a target **after** trying to compile it.

just change the position of those two lines:

- first define the target
- link the library.

like this

```
add_executable(OpenCV_Basics ${SOURCE_FILES})
target_link_libraries(OpenCV_Basics )
```

Answer (score 11):

When any CMake command accepts *target* argument, it expects given target to be **already created**.

Correct usage:

```
# Create target 'OpenCV_Basics' 
add_executable(OpenCV_Basics ${SOURCE_FILES})
# Pass the target to other commands
target_link_libraries(OpenCV_Basics ${OpenCV_LIBRARIES})
```